# Where to find a list of available linking libraries in C

Tags: c, gcc, include, header-files

For example, if I include `<math.h>` what resource would I reference to find out I need to link it with `-lm`?

Comment: That would be in the documentation for your compiler (you added a GCC tag, so you're presumable using that).

Comment: The way I do it is:  via brute force.  If it does not link, and the link failures are for items other than your source code, then some library is needed.

Comment: It is unfortunately often difficult.  Note that merely including `<math.h>` in no way implies that `-lm` is needed.  Perhaps the header is included merely to get a constant definition.

Comment: The linker will tell you in the form of undefined symbol errors. If you look up these symbols (e.g. using `man`) you should be able to find which library they belong to and then add it to your linker flags.

Comment: Seems like there is, unfortunately, no such reference. Thank you for the responses.